# Can't find config directory in JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, directory, config

This is my directory structure:

```
/node
. /config
  . default.js
. node_modules
. /controllers
  . myfile.js
  . other files
. app.js
```

And here's some of code written in myfile.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const config = require('config');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const moment = require('moment');
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: '*/*'}));
var client;
const redis = require("redis");
client = redis.createClient();

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

const connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
    host: config.get('database.host'),
    user: config.get('database.user'),
    password: config.get('database.password'),
    database: config.get('database.dbname'),
    connectionLimit: 2
});

function selectUpdatedData() {

    connectionPool.query("SELECT * FROM rc_devices_notifications", function (err, rows, fields) {
        //DO STUFF
        process.exit();
    });
}

selectUpdatedData();
```

Now, when I run this file using `node myfile.js`, I see following error:

> ```
> WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:/home/rc-user/node/controllers/config
> WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
> /home/rc-user/node/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:181
>     throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
>     ^
>
> Error: Configuration property "database.host" is not defined
>     at Config.get (/home/rc-user/node/node_modules/config/lib/config.js:181:11)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/rc-user/node/controllers/update_trackers.js:20:18)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
>     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
>     at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
>     at run (bootstrap_node.js:420:7)
>     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:139:9)
> ```

However, when I run app.js (my server, that too uses config), it shows no error. It gets config files.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The **default.json** file:

```
{
  "database" : {
    "host" :"something",
    "user" : "something",
    "password" : "something",
    "dbname" : "something"
  },
  "parameters" : {
    "apnkey" : "something",
    "apnkeyid" : "something",
    "apnteamid" : "something",
    "googleAPI" : "something",
    "authorization" : "something",
    "push_app_id" : "something"
  }
}
```

This is the config file (default.json) in config directory.

Comment: can you post the config file also, maybe there is some problem ?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: please try running app from the root folder like: `node controllers/myfile.js`

Comment: The config seems ok, and the configuration also, maybe you are exporting a different environment like `export NODE_ENV=production` or other and it can't find your configuration...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have in error

> No configurations found in configuration directory:/home/rc-user/node/controllers/config

Since you are starting your app from subfolder, the `config` package is finding the config directory from that relative path.

Please use

```
node controllers/myfile.js
```

So that `config` will find the config directory from the root of the project.

You can use environment variable `NODE_CONFIG_DIR` for setting custom config directory path. Read more about [NODE_CONFIG_DIR](https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Environment-Variables#node_config_dir).

> The default NODE_CONFIG_DIR is the `/config` directory under the current working directory

Comment: Yeah, it worked. But isn't there any way to specify this path somewhere for my config folder?

Comment: if this answers your question, please consider accepting it as an answer.